# Yii2 disable pjax in GridView pagination

Tags: gridview, pagination, yii2, pager

How can I disable pjax for the pagination part of the gridview? Everything else sould work with pjax except pagination. Is that possible?

The reason for that is because I want to send allot of POST data when changing pages. Sessions are not an option.

My Gridview:

```
    echo GridView::widget
    ([
        'id' => 'list_of_products',
        'dataProvider' => $products,
        'filterModel' => $productProvider,
        'filterSelector' => 'select[name="per-page"]',
        'summary' => '<div class="summary">Showing <b>' . $products->getTotalCount() . '</b> products</div>',
        'columns' =>
            [
                ....
            ],
        'pjax' => true,
        'responsive' => true,
        'responsiveWrap' => false,
        'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => [
            'id' => 'kv-pjax-container',
            'enablePushState' => false,
            'options' => ['class' => 'row col-lg-6']
        ]],
        'panel' => [
            'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"> Search result</h3>',
            'headingOptions' => ['class' => 'panel-heading product-container'],
            'beforeOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-panel-before'],
        ],
        'export' => [
            'label' => 'Page',
            'fontAwesome' => true,
        ],
        'toolbar' => [
            ['content' =>
                ''
            ],
        ],
        'toolbar' => [
            '<div class="form-group pull-right">
                <button onclick="addToList()" type="button" id="clear-filters" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Add to feed
                </button>
            </div>'
        ]
    ]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may disable pjax for a specific link inside the container by adding data-pjax="0" attribute to this link.

In your grid just set options 'pager':

```
echo GridView::widget
([
    'id' => 'list_of_products',
    ...
    'pager' => [
        'linkOptions'=> ['data-pjax' => '0']
    ],
]);
```

Documentation: 
[LinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$linkOptions-detail)

Comment: when i use bootstrap4 it breaks. `'pager' =>[
                    'linkOptions'=> ['data-pjax' => '0'],
                    'class' => \yii\bootstrap4\LinkPager::class,
                ],` any idea how to fix this?